# How do I set fields in ModelForm externally in Django?

Tags: python, django-forms, django-views

My current setup in `views.py` looks like this

```
def order_detail(request, pk):
    order = Order.objects.get(pk=pk)

    # Define the can_something variables here.

    include_fields = []

    if can_edit_work_type:
        include_fields.append('work_type')
    if can_edit_vendor:
        include_fields.append('vendor')
    if can_edit_note:
        include_fields.append('note')

    class OrderDetailForm(forms.ModelForm):
        class Meta:
            model = Order
            fields = tuple(include_fields)

    form = OrderDetailForm(instance=order, data=request.POST)

    return render(request, 'doors/order/detail.html', {'order': order, 'form': form})
```

Obviously I think it's best practice to define `OrderDetailForm` inside `forms.py` instead of `views.py`. So how do I move `OrderDetailForm` to `forms.py` and still pass `include_fields`?

I tried something like this but it didn't work

`views.py`

```
def order_detail(request, pk):
    order = Order.objects.get(pk=pk)

    # Define the can_something variables here.

    include_fields = []

    if can_edit_work_type:
        include_fields.append('work_type')
    if can_edit_vendor:
        include_fields.append('vendor')
    if can_edit_note:
        include_fields.append('note')

    form = OrderDetailForm(instance=order, data=request.POST, include_fields=include_fields)

    return render(request, 'doors/order/detail.html', {'order': order, 'form': form})
```

`forms.py`

```
class OrderDetailForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Order

    def __init__(self, include_fields, *args, **kwargs):
        super(OrderDetailForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.Meta.fields = tuple(include_fields)
```

But that didn't work; it included all the fields on the model. I'm assuming the problem is in the object orientation.

Any tips or suggestions are welcomed. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to modify `self.fields` in the initializer, removing keys in the mapping not found in the sequence.

Comment: Iterate over `self.fields`. Remove keys that aren't in the sequence.

Comment: So is `self.fields` a list of a dictionary? I don't understand if I am suppose to do something like `self.fields = ('one', 'two')` or do I have to explicity set something like `self.fields['one'] = SomeFieldInput()` (but then what's the point of having `ModelForm` if I have to explicity state the field inputs). What if I do something like `class Meta: fields = ()`, then that means `self.fields` is initially empty?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the Django code, you might want to try using `self._meta.fields = tuple(include_fields)`.

Comment: It didn't work, that allowed all the fields in the `Order` model.

Comment: Try moving the `Meta`-munging to above the `super()` call.

Comment: Like swap the line `self._meta.fields = tuple(include_fields)` and `super(OrderDetailForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)`? That still didn't work. It still shows every field.