# How do I change a field in an inner class from an outer class in Python?

Tags: python, django, oop

Suppose I have a class like

```
class SomeModel(BaseModel):
    class Meta:
        # foo = ('one', 'two') # I want to modify this.

    def __init__(self, some_arg, *args, **kwargs)
        super(SomeModel, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        # From here I want to somehow set SomeModel.Meta.foo to some_arg
```

I create an instance with `SomeModel(some_arg=('one', 'two'))` and I want to modify `SomeModel.Meta.foo` as `('one', 'two')`.

In case anyone is wondering why I want to do this, it's a problem I currently have in Django with [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10660994/how-do-i-set-fields-in-modelform-externally-in-django).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Django the `Meta` inner class no longer exists once the model is created, since the metaclass strips it out. You will need to find another way to do this.

Comment: Ugh, ok. I'll just not use `ModelForm`.